# How to match a US phone number pattern in a case statement

Tags: bash, switch-statement

So I am only looking to match that format particularily: xxxxxxxxxx

At the moment I have:

```
case $num in
 [0-9]{10}) echo "$num"   ;;
         *) echo "no num" ;;
esac
```

But unfortunately, it doesn't work and I simply cannot find why.
What is wrong with this pattern matching?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
num=1234567890

case $num in
  [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]) echo "$num" ;;
  *) echo "no num" ;;
esac
```

Output:

```
1234567890
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because `case` supports glob pattern matching and `[0-9]{10}` is a regex.

You will need to use `=~` operator in `if` to use regex:

```
if [[ $num =~ ^[0-9]{10}$ ]]; then
   echo "$num"
else
   echo "no num"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternate version using the `if` statement, it is shorter and cleaner but the original question was with the use of `case` statement.

Comment: Yes it was but original question was also using regex. You have to sacrifice either regex or case. I would personally not use something that even I can't read later.